# Audacity Keeps Crashing

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, crash, audacity, playback

I'm running the latest version of audacity and the playback keeps crashing when I try to pause it. Ive seen elsewhere on line that this is a bug and that there are workarounds for it but i cant seem to figure out the workarounds. I have tried launching audacity with the code "export PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 && audacity" in the terminal but this does not change the issue. I have tried downloading Audio Jack connection kit which theoretically will allow me to change my audio from ALSA to Jackd in audacity but I can't seem to figure out how to make work Jack Audio. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a little strange, but I had this crashing problem today with a new, clean install on 16.04 & it stopped happening when I didn't bother to maximise the window. Audacity always seems to open un-maximised, I usually maximise it straight away. This time I didn't. No Problems.

Not relevant to the original question but may be of interest: this also cured the clicking & stuttering I was suffering during playback.